# Access GIF frames with C#

Tags: c#, gif, animated-gif

I'm a beginner in C#.
I would like to know if there's a way to access different frames inside a GIF animation with C#.
I'm using Visual Studio 2008.

Answer (score 28):

Try this:

```
using System.Drawing;    
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

Image gifImg = Image.FromFile(pathToGifFile);
FrameDimension dimension = new FrameDimension(gifImg.FrameDimensionsList[0]);
// Number of frames
int frameCount = gifImg.GetFrameCount(dimension);
// Return an Image at a certain index
gifImg.SelectActiveFrame(dimension, index);
```

Comment: What part of .net are Image and FrameDimension found in?

Comment: @aj.toulan For Image, System.Drawing; for FrameDimension, System.Drawing.Imaging.

Comment: Just to say if you are using Visual Studio place the cursor on the type that doesn't have the namespace included and press "Ctrl+." , if you have the right namespace added already as a reference in your project it will give you an option in the drop-down to auto add the namespace decoration.

Comment: isn't SelectActiveFrame return an integer?

Comment: @AaA after calling SelectActiveFrame you simply draw or use the Image normally.  The object's internals will ensure the specified frame's bitmap is used.

Answer (score 9):

a bit of googling: [editing animated gif's in c#](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/fcb7d14d-d15b-4336-971c-94a80e34b85e)

> You can read the animated Gif with Image.GetFrameCount() and SelectActiveFrame().

Comment: This answer also includes information about getting the timing information out in additional to the frames

Comment: I would not recommend the answer as a good one, generally speaking. You do not need to make a bitmap every time you draw or use a frame. The SelectActiveFrame ensures that when the image is drawn, the specified frame will be used.