# Adding text to an image file

Tags: c#

I need to add text to an image file. I need to read one image file (jpg,png,gif) and I need add one line text to it.

Comment: Looking into it. The problem is that when you open the file, it is locked so you can't save to the same file. Will get back to you...

Answer (score 21):

Well in GDI+ you would read in the file using a Image class and then use the Graphics class to add text to it. Something like:

```
  Image image = Image.FromFile(@"c:\somepic.gif"); //or .jpg, etc...
  Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(image);
  graphics.DrawString("Hello", this.Font, Brushes.Black, 0, 0);
```

If you want to save the file over the old one, the code has to change a bit as the Image.FromFile() method locks the file until it's disposed. The following is what I came up with:

```
  FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"c:\somepic.gif", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
  Image image = Image.FromStream(fs);
  fs.Close();

  Bitmap b = new Bitmap(image);
  Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(b);
  graphics.DrawString("Hello", this.Font, Brushes.Black, 0, 0);

  b.Save(@"c:\somepic.gif", image.RawFormat);

  image.Dispose();
  b.Dispose();
```

I would test this quite thoroughly though :)

Comment: Just playing devil's advocate here: you'll obviously need to save it afterwards!

Comment: Hopefully the above will help.

Comment: how to rotate this text and then add to the image?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421381/how-to-rotate-text-in-gdi for rotating GDI+ text. Also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2966316/how-do-i-superimpose-one-bitmap-image-on-another-in-gdi because you would in this case have to write and rotate the text on another bitmap and then super impose it over the picture.

Answer (score 1):

Specifically for gifs to have a gif result, you should write on each frame like the following:

```
string originalImgPath = @"C:\test.gif";
Image IMG = Image.FromFile(originalImgPath);
FrameDimension dimension = new FrameDimension(IMG.FrameDimensionsList[0]);
int frameCount = IMG.GetFrameCount(dimension);
int Length = frameCount;
GifBitmapEncoder gEnc = new GifBitmapEncoder();
for (int i = 0; i < Length; i++)
{
    // Get each frame
    IMG.SelectActiveFrame(dimension, i);
    var aFrame = new Bitmap(IMG);

    // write one the selected frame
    Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(aFrame);
    graphics.DrawString("Hello", new Font("Arial", 24, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold), System.Drawing.Brushes.Black, 50, 50);
    var bmp = aFrame.GetHbitmap();
    var src = System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
                bmp,
                IntPtr.Zero,
                Int32Rect.Empty,
                BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
    // merge frames
    gEnc.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(src));
}

string saveImgFile = @"C:\modified_test.gif"
using (FileStream fs2 = new FileStream(saveImgFile, FileMode.Create))
{
    gEnc.Save(fs2);
}
```

I should have mentioned that getting gif frames from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540701/access-gif-frames-with-c-sharp).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using the Graphics object in C#. You can get a Graphics object from the picture ( image.CreateGraphics() - or something like this as I remember ) and the use some of the built in methods for adding text to it like : Graphycs.DrawString() or other related methods.