# How to rotate Text in GDI+?

Tags: c#, gdi+

I want to display an given string in a specific angle. I tried to to do this with the `System.Drawing.Font` class. Here is my code:

`Font boldFont = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 12, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, 1, true);

graphics.DrawString("test", boldFont, textBrush, 0, 0);`

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
String theString = "45 Degree Rotated Text";
SizeF sz = e.Graphics.VisibleClipBounds.Size;
//Offset the coordinate system so that point (0, 0) is at the
center of the desired area.
e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(sz.Width / 2, sz.Height / 2);
//Rotate the Graphics object.
e.Graphics.RotateTransform(45);
sz = e.Graphics.MeasureString(theString, this.Font);
//Offset the Drawstring method so that the center of the string matches the center.
e.Graphics.DrawString(theString, this.Font, Brushes.Black, -(sz.Width/2), -(sz.Height/2));
//Reset the graphics object Transformations.
e.Graphics.ResetTransform();
```

Taken from [here](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/32846836/rotation-of-text.aspx).

Answer (score 10):

You can use the `RotateTransform` method ([see MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.rotatetransform.aspx)) to specify rotation for all drawing on `Graphics` (including text drawn using `DrawString`). The `angle` is in degrees:

```
graphics.RotateTransform(angle)
```

If you want to do just a single rotated operation, then you can reset the transform to the original state by calling `RotateTransform` again with negative angle (alternatively, you can use `ResetTransform`, but that will clear *all* transformations that you applied which may not be what you want):

```
graphics.RotateTransform(-angle)
```

Comment: I already tried this, but then all my drawn Graphics are rotated. Thats help not very much.

Comment: @eagle999 use ResetTransform() after you are done drawing the rotated text

Answer (score 9):

If you want a method to draw a rotated string at the strings center position, then try the following method:

```
public void drawRotatedText(Bitmap bmp, int x, int y, float angle, string text, Font font, Brush brush)
{
  Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
  g.TranslateTransform(x, y); // Set rotation point
  g.RotateTransform(angle); // Rotate text
  g.TranslateTransform(-x, -y); // Reset translate transform
  SizeF size = g.MeasureString(text, font); // Get size of rotated text (bounding box)
  g.DrawString(text, font, brush, new PointF(x - size.Width / 2.0f, y - size.Height / 2.0f)); // Draw string centered in x, y
  g.ResetTransform(); // Only needed if you reuse the Graphics object for multiple calls to DrawString
  g.Dispose();
}
```

Best regards
  Hans Milling...

Comment: You are the hero!! Thanks.