# Drawing a Rotated Text to an Image in C#

Tags: c#, .net, graphics, drawing, rotation

I'm using the the drawstring method of Graphics class to draw a String on Image.

```
  g.DrawString(mytext, font, brush, 0, 0);
```

I'm trying to rotate the text by angle using the Rotate Transform Function of the graphic object so that the text can be drawn at any angle.How can i do it using Rotate Transform.
The rotate Transform Code i used is

```
    Bitmap m = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
    Graphics x=Graphics.FromImage(m);
    x.RotateTransform(30);
    SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
    x.DrawString("hi", font,brush,image.Width/2,image.Height/2);
//image=picturebox1.image
    pictureBox1.Image = m;
```

The Text is Drawn at a rotated angle but it is not drawn at the centre as i want.Plz help me out.

Comment: Show us the rotation transform code that you tried.

Comment: Can you show us the entire method (for example, is this the OnPaint event)?  Also, can you tell us what results you are getting?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It's not enough to just `RotateTransform` or `TranslateTranform` if you want to center the text.  You need to offset the starting point of the text, too, by measuring it:

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)) {
  g.TranslateTransform(bmp.Width / 2, bmp.Height / 2);
  g.RotateTransform(30);
  SizeF textSize = g.MeasureString("hi", font);
  g.DrawString("hi", font, Brushes.Red, -(textSize.Width / 2), -(textSize.Height / 2));
}
```

From [How to rotate Text in GDI+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421381/how-to-rotate-text-in-gdi/4421398#4421398)

Comment: @LarsTech.Works like a Charm.Can you help me do this in the case of an image.I have added the Code Please see.

Answer (score 3):

before `g.DrawString(mytext, font, brush, 0, 0);` use `g.RotateTransform(45);`